# Should I still wait for the job?

Tags: job-offer

I recently interviewed for a company. I received a mail from the recruiter in two days that interviews went well and offer would be extended by that week end. Later after one week I was asked to share my visa details. Since I have only 2.3 years left on my H1B visa, they are finding it difficult to do Green Card(GC) for me, since the company will do GC only after one year of employment. They need to take some exception to start GC earlier in my case. After couple of weeks the recruiter said they are working getting the exception. Now its the 4 the week. I heard from the recruiter that they are interviewing another person so that they can try to get someone without the above mentioned exception. I already waited for 4 weeks for the offer letter. They said they will take me if the new person is not taken and they will need one more week for that.  Should I wait more with expectation?

Comment: *"Should I wait more with expectation?"* - Do you have any other choice?

Comment: I am already in a job...bt is an abusive work culture.. so i am desperatly looking for another job..

Answer (score 11):

If by wait you mean sit around and not pursue other job opportunities then I would say no.  As it stands, you don't have a job so you should still be searching and applying to positions.  If this company offers you a job before you have joined a new company then you can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Odds are that you have become the 'backup plan' for this opening. I would keep communications open if you really want this position, but I would also actively be looking  since this doesn't sound very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You've become the second choice.

You could force the issue by setting a deadline for them to hire you but since they are struggling with the GC they'll probably remove you completely from the process then.